# Why can't CSRF be used to steal data? Why does it only affect state-changing actions?

Tags: csrf

I have been searching on the internet for a few days for the answer to a question, which seemingly noone is asking:

**Why can attackers not use csrf to steal data?**

I understand that the victim's browser is executing the attack. But many examples i have found, propose luring the victim onto a malicious website which then automatically executes the attack.

Especially interesting to me are not the simple attacks via link (optionally embedded into an img) or via a post form, but those which utilise XMLHttpRequests. In case of a malicious website, no XSS is needed to perform a CSRF attack with JS only.

But then the response-handler of the XMLHttpRequest would receive the response of the forged request and could easily relay that information to an attacker via a second xhr.

Is it simply a case of how it is defined, and where we draw the line? Is it, that the data extraction within the response handler is 'technically' a separate follow-up attack?

At least to me it is very confusing, that seemingly every source says CSRF can only be useful against state-changing actions.

Edit:
I assume that SOP/CORS are missing or misconfigured in a way which allows this to happen. Or for instance the user using an outdated browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can CSRF attacks steal log in information?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112149/can-csrf-attacks-steal-log-in-information), [Can the attacker view the response from a CSRF attack request?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/203556/can-the-attacker-view-the-response-from-a-csrf-attack-request), [Are CSRF Attacks Really Blind](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35924/are-csrf-attacks-really-blind)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't read data is the [**Same-Origin Policy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). In simple terms, a script can only read data from a different *origin* if that origin allows it via their CORS header.

#### An example:

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser to open the JavaScript console and type (or paste) the following example code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://example.com');
xhr.send();
```

You will see the following error message pop up:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at `'https://example.com/'` from origin `'https://security.stackexchange.com'` has been blocked by CORS policy: No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is present on the requested resource.

So even if you attempted to access `xhr.response` now, you'll get an empty string. So just by controlling the JavaScript executed by the client on your site, you can't make the client send arbitrary HTTP requests *and* read their responses.

#### CSRF without XHR

But CSRF attacks don't actually employ XHR requests, because as we have seen, the browser will refuse to execute those requests. CSRF attacks use, as you said, other methods of sending GET or POST requests.

For GET requests, you could use an `<img src=target>` tag. And while this will indeed cause the browser to send a GET request, there is no way for the client to read the response to this request via JavaScript. In fact, modern browsers implement something called "Cross-Origin Read Blocking". If you attempt to insert `<img src="https://example.com">` into your site, then the browser will send the GET request, but the browser will refuse to insert the response into the DOM if it has a MIME-Type that doesn't correspond to an image. The request still has to be sent, because the browser has no way of knowing beforehand if the response isn't a valid image to be included.

For POST requests, what is typically done is to create a form on a HTML page and then submit the form automatically upon loading the page via JavaScript. However, this is not an XHR request, it's a regular form submission. And if you create a form with an action on another domain, your own JavaScript in your attacker-controlled domain can no longer read the response of that form submission. So again, you cannot read the response of the request.

#### In Summary

- For XHR requests sent with JavaScript, **Same-Origin Policy** blocks you from reading the response, unless the target domain sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow your origin.
- For GET requests sent via  tags or similar, **Cross-Origin Read Blocking** prevents you from reading the response to the request, although it does *not* prevent the request from being sent.
- For POST requests, the nature of the  tag makes it impossible to read the response of the form.

In both the second and third case, the request itself will still be sent. So if the request causes a side-effect or "state-change", that side-effect will still be observed, even if you don't see the direct response to it. But if an admit sends a POST request to `/api/users/createUser` with data you control, then the side effect of a user being created for you is what you really care about, not the response `{"success": true}`.

Comment: _CSRF attacks don't actually employ XHR requests, because as we have seen, the browser will refuse to execute those requests._ Not true; as long as a request sent with `fetch` or XHR remains _simple_ (in CORS terms), the browser will happily comply without triggering a preflight. Try it for yourself.